# Certain property of a bus admittance matrix

Tags: power-engineering, matrix

I have got a simple network for my assignment:

[image]

I know bus admittance matrix have certain properties that let us form the matrix without writing so many lines of `KCL`. But is there any property such that one could, without matrix formation, say `sum of values in row 2 of the matrix is zero, whereas the sum of values in row 4 is –j1`?

I have formed the admittance matrix and I can confirm that above statement is true but I was wondering what is the rationale behind that statement?

Comment: Can you be more clear what's meant by the "Y bus matrix". That isn't a term that's used universally in the EE field, as far as I know. Are you making an admittance matrix for the network? What are the ports of the network (all the nodes numbered 0 thru 6)? What is the reference node?

Comment: @ThePhoton I thought it is pretty self explanatory but maybe I was wrong. I edited the post and replaced the term 'Y bus'. The reference node is node 0. I don't really know what you mean by network ports?!

Comment: When you make an admittance matrix, you're making a way to calculate the current at one port due to a voltage applied at another port. But you first have to define what are the ports of your network.

Comment: Wikipedia says that the "bus admittance matrix" is used in power engineering. Is that the context you're asking this question in?

Comment: Looking at Wiki, I think the answer is that the sum of values in any row is equal to the self-admittance to ground (so for row 4 it's 1j). The sum in row 2 is zero because bus 2 has no self-admittance (no admittance from bus 2 to ground).

Comment: But this may only account for the simplest cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `The Photon` for the heads up. I found the comprehensive answer in following textbook:

**Rau, NS 2003, 'Appendix B: Network Equations', in Optimization Principles: Practical Applications to the Operation and Markets of the Electric Power Industry, Wiley, p. 310.**

In a nutshell:

`In an admittance matrix the algebraic sum of values in any row is equal to shunt admittance connecting that particular node to the reference node (ground)`.